# proof of parallelogram using vector and midpoint

Tags: vector-analysis

$OPQR$ is a parallelogram. $T$ is the midpoint of $OR$. Show that $QT$ cuts the diagonal $PR$ in the ratio $2:1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the symmetric of $Q$ wrt $R$. Since $\frac{PQ}{TR}=2$, $S$ is the simmetric of $P$ wrt $T$, too. This gives that the intersection of $PR$ and $QT$ is the centroid of the triangle $PQS$, and since the medians cut themselves in thirds, the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the intersection point of $QT$ and $PR$.

Since $M$ is on the $QT$, there exists $k\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$\vec{QM}=k\vec{QT}=k\left(\vec{QR}+\frac 12\vec{QP}\right)=k\vec{QR}+\frac{k}{2}\vec{QP}\tag1$$
On the other hand, since $M$ is on the $PR$, there exists $l$ such that 
$$\vec{QM}=(1-l)\vec{QR}+l\vec{QP}\tag2$$

Since we have $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$k=1-l\ \text{and}\ \frac k2=l\Rightarrow (k,l)=\left(\frac 23,\frac 13\right).$$

So, the answer is $PM:MR=1-l:l=2/3:1/3=2:1$.

Comment: pls solve this using "vector geometry" to show that QT cuts the diagonal PR in the ratio 2:1

Comment: @sekling: I added it. Is there anything unclear?

Comment: Pls show detail QM =(1−l)QR+lQP

Comment: @sekling: Since $M$ is on the line segment $PR$, there exists $l$ such that $\vec{QM}=(1-l)\vec{QR}+l\vec{QP}$. This means that $PM:MR=1-l:l$. (See the triangle $QPR$.) I'm sure that you can find this in your textbook.

Comment: @sekling: We can write $\vec{QZ}=m\vec{QR}+l\vec{QP}$ for any point $Z$ on the plane. If $Z$ is a point on the line $PR$, then $l+m=1\iff m=1-l$. So we have $\vec{QZ}=(1-l)\vec{QR}+l\vec{QP}$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find this information in my textbook. (QM=(1−l)QR+lQP ). Do you have other ways to prove QT cuts the diagonal PR in the ratio 2:1.

Comment: @sekling: Well, this is a fundamental issue. I would like you to understand (memolize) it. So let me explain it more. Suppose that we have a triangle $OAB$ and that $P$ is on the line segment $AB$. Now, there exists $t$ such that $\vec{AP}=t\vec{AB}$ (agree?). And, this equals $\vec{OP}-\vec{OA}=t(\vec{OB}-\vec{OA})$, which can be simplified as $\vec{OP}=(1-t)\vec{OA}+t\vec{OB}$. This is what we want. I hope this helps!

Comment: EXCELLENT...THANKS

Comment: @sekling: You are welcome!